# Как проверить открыт ли файл с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файлы

я хочу написать программу которая бесконечно проверяет открыт ли некоторый файл *.txt
Как сделать саму проверку?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не понял. То есть если кто-то другой читает файл - программа должна это обнаружить?

Comment: Извините, совершенно верно @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Пробовать открыть в эксклюзивном режиме и смотреть на результат?... но так будет перекрываться доступ к файлу.

Comment: На уровне app это сделать не возможно, только на уровне драйвера. Но есть другая фишка, можно поставить "вотчера", который сообщит о том, что другая программа изменила файл. Так например делает студия, если паралельно в блокноте отредактировать открытый файл проэкта - если это оно - переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Если уровень драйвера - то я вижу вариант - просканировать таблицы дескрипторов, и опросить пути к файлам в открытых дескрипторах. Как именно это сделать - не знаю. Как минимум начать с "нулевого" драйвера, или поискать в сети готовый шлюз на опрос всех файловых дескрипторов. Или задействовать handles.exe от sysinternals.

Comment: @nick_n_a
К сожалению надо чтобы программа увидела что файл открыли его не обязательно будут изменять.

Comment: @Harry
Можно узнать по подробнее как именно сделать эксклюзивный доступ к файлу возможно это решит проблему.

Comment: @DrochilyCastle, в \*nix есть утилита `fuser`, которая умеет делать, что вам надо. [Смежники из enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43227322/7286264) говорят, что есть ее порт в винду. Может ссылка там вам поможет

Comment: @DrochilyCastle, нет  эксклюзивный доступ к файлу в общем случае не решит проблему, в windows программы обычно по умолчанию открывают эксклюзивно в отличие от *nix, но могут открыть и без этого

Comment: @avp  


Если в курсе, то расскажи как применять ибо пока что ничего годного я не нашёл.
В моём случае под винду делаю.

Comment: @DrochilyCastle, в винде я не пишу. В linux можно исследовать состояние [/proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). В тех *nix-ах где такого интерфейса нет, как я предполагаю, fuser должен читать /dev/kmem (память ядра) и смотреть в списке tasks открытые файлы

Answer (score 0):

Если используешь fstream, то есть функция is_open.
Значение true, если файл открыт; в противном случае — значение false.

Comment: Здесь вопрос про другое -- открыт ли файл кем-то еще в системе. Почитайте комментарии. Просто сам вопрос несколько неудачно сформулирован